# Black screen after "starting windows"

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, display

I am using Win7 Enterprise in a laptop. It has two display adapters, one being nvidia geforce GS 9300m and Mobile Intel(R) 4 series Express Chipset Family. When I normally boot up, all I could see after "starting windows", is a black screen with my cursor on it.

I could it only boot it in safe mode, or in 640x800 resolution. I have tried to change Mobile PC display to Nvidia Default Flat Panel, but it said it is unable to save display settings. I think that is the problem. I believe there are no conflicting devices. Please HELP me :( , I just upgraded from windows vista and I made a clean install.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does the same behavior happen?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Use that information to identify the service or process that is causing the problem.

Comment: How would I do that? By using windows task manager?

Comment: No;  You don't boot everything then you add, one by one, your other services and processes that are normally started when you log into your profile.

Comment: Whaaa??? howw?? (sorry I'm really dumb)

Comment: You manually one by one eliminate the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Okay, one time after I was done with playing in 640x800 resolution, I booted normally. I tried changing my main display (from Mobile Intel(R) 4 series Express Chipset display into Nvidia Default Panel), and unfortunately I was only able to do it in 1280x780 resolution. Just after that, I ran a game, only to result into a BSOD and a reboot.

Comment: Why are you telling me that?  You are suppose to determine which service or process is causing your problems, by determining which services and processes do not cause the problem, no reason to make additional comments until you find the culprit and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Start computer and hit <kbd>F8</kbd>. Select low resolution mode. Go into your screen resolution and set it to what you want. Now go into the Nvidia Control Panel and set its resolution to the same you selected. Should work with a normal start now.

Answer (score 0):

This has recently happened to one of our customers was solved in this way:

1. Download a offline version of your graphics drivers.(Just in case)
2. Start Windows in Safe Mode.
3. With the combination of keys Win + R, type "devmgmt.msc" without
   quotes   Look for the section, "Display adapters".
4. Look for your graphic card adapter (Nvidia,AMD,Intel)
5. Right click on your graphic card, and select "uninstall"
6. When done, reboot Windows normally, you should can see the graphics
   again (but blurry because the lack of graphic drivers)
7. Wait for Windows to download the drivers again (required internet
   connection)
8. Install or let Windows install the drivers.

P.D:Check your energy profile after the reinstall sometimes switch to "Low".